# Sending an Intent from C++ via JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-intent, java-native-interface

I am trying to make an explicit intent call (intent to a specific pkg and class) from C++ via JNI.  Everything is fine until the last line where I am actually trying to send the intent:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(obj, startActivity, intentObject);
```

I dont get an android error, it is just a full dump/stack trace...which does not give me any helpful info.

Here is the C++ code making the call to start an intent:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_testpkg_test(JNIEnv *java_env, jobject obj) {
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&java_env, 0);
    jclass activityClass = java_env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jmethodID appGetContextId = java_env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "getApplicationContext", "()Landroid/content/Context;");
    jobject appContext = java_env->CallObjectMethod(obj, appGetContextId);

    //Get an instance of Intent
    jclass intentClass = java_env->FindClass("android/content/Intent");
    jmethodID newIntent = java_env->GetMethodID(intentClass, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject intentObject = java_env->NewObject(intentClass, newIntent);
    java_env->CallVoidMethod(intentObject, newIntent);

    //Get an instance of the ComponentName class
    jclass componentClass = java_env->FindClass("android/content/ComponentName");
    jmethodID componentMID = java_env->GetMethodID(componentClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring pkgName =java_env->NewStringUTF("com.testpkg");
    jstring clsName =java_env->NewStringUTF("com.testpkg.test");
    jobject componentObj = java_env->NewObject(componentClass, componentMID, pkgName, clsName);
    java_env->CallVoidMethod(componentObj, componentMID, pkgName, clsName);

    //Calling intent.setComponentName passing in pkg+class name
    jmethodID setComponentName = java_env->GetMethodID(intentClass, "setComponent","(Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/content/Intent;");
    java_env->CallObjectMethod(intentObject, setComponentName, componentObj);

    //Call getapplicationcontext().startActivity(intent)
    jmethodID startActivity = java_env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, startActivity, intentObject);
}
```

Comment: First off-  why?  This is going to be called from Java, doing it via JNI will be orders of magnitude slower.  Doing this in C is pointless.  Secondly, you aren't error checking any of your return values.  Most likely something is null.  Third, I assume this is being called on an Activity object, right?  Otherwise this won't work, as its assuming the "this" pointer to the java object is an activity.

Comment: re why - I requirements which prevent me from calling back into Java to make the intent call.
re error-checking - I omitted that to make the code easier to read.  But, I am indeed checking each value.
re "this is being called on an Activity object" - I dont understand this question...pls elaborate.

Comment: He means the `obj` here `Java_com_testpkg_test(JNIEnv *java_env, jobject obj)` must be an Activity.

Comment: @Simon - The initial JNI call was made from an Activity, so my assumption is, it is.

Comment: But, to elaborate - I am not using NativeActivity.  Just my java class is extending Activity.

Answer (score 1):

The comments I posted still apply, but here's a problem-  don't call `java_env->CallVoidMethod(intentObject, newIntent)`.  The NewObject call does it for you.  You do this twice, its likely to be screwing up Java's memory management.

Comment: Does that also apply for the following line -       
java_env->CallVoidMethod(componentObj, componentMID, pkgName, clsName);

Comment: Yes.  NewObject calls the constructor your pass in.

Comment: unfortunately, that didnt fix the issue.